# Dynamic routing is not working in nuxt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nuxt.js

I want to have(created) dynamic route like as provided in [nuxt docs](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#dynamic-nested-routes)

```
pages/projects/
              /_id.vue
              /_id/details.vue
```

But everytime I call url `localhost/projects/1/details/` , it is rendering `_id.vue` page instead of `/_id/details.vue` !! How to do correctly ?

Answer (score 5):

Your _id.vue structure should contain `<nuxt-child>` component in order to render it's child `details.vue` correctly.

Your folder structure then looks like this:

```
└── pages
    └── projects
        ├── _id
        │   └── details.vue
        └── _id.vue
```

Having this folder structure produces router with setup like this:

```
routes: [
    {
        path: "/projects/:id?",
        component: ProjectsId,
        name: "projects-id",
        children: [
            {
                path: "details",
                component: ProjectsIdDetails,
                name: "projects-id-details"
            }
        ]
    },
```

That means your code could look something like this:

**_id.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>(_id.vue) Project: {{ $route.params.id }}</h1>
    <nuxt-child/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

**_id/details.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    (_id/details.vue) Project: {{ $route.params.id }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

**TIP:** If you come to situation where you are not sure about your routing, open your `.nuxt/router.js` after nuxt build is done. There you will find `function createRouter()` which will help you debug routes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to config Nuxt-Child. Take a look https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-nuxt-child